# How to send data (integer) from c++ to Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

Please help me. This is my program and the output. But there is so much noise like this:

-168<\0>????????????????<\b>?@????????????????????<15>????????????@??<\n>????????@P?<\n>????????<\0><\0>?C<\0><\0>?C????LHm???O<1>?%?<\0>??O<1>???<\0><21><2><\0><\0> <\0><\0><\0>X?P<1>?????<\b><24><\0><\0><2><\0><\0><\0><\0><\0><\0>?

My program:

```
float yaw, pitch, roll;
quaternion.GetEulerAngles<Axis_Y, Axis_X, Axis_Z>(&yaw, &pitch, &roll);
wzPrintf(20, 110, "Yaw:%d, Pitch:%d, Roll:%d", yaww, pitchh, rolll);
yaws = (int)RadToDegree(yaw);
pitchs = (int)RadToDegree(pitch);
rolls = (int)RadToDegree(roll);
yaww = (int)RadToDegree(yaw);
pitchh = (int)RadToDegree(pitch);
rolll = (int)RadToDegree(roll);
char out[10];
SerialPort arduino(port_name);
if (arduino.isConnected()) { wzPrintf(20, 130, "Connection established"); }
else wzPrintf(20, 130, "ERROR, check port name");
sprintf_s(out, "%d", yaww);
arduino.writeSerialPort(out, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't send the entire buffer.
I suspect that this should do it:

```
arduino.writeSerialPort(out, strlen(out));
```